# Как правильно хранить ссылки, большие строки в коде Python?

Tags: python, рефакторинг

Как правильно хранить ссылки, большие строки в коде Python? Правильно ли оставлять ссылки, headers в коде или их нужно куда-то выносить?

Comment: Можно в отдельный .py файл проекта. И потом импортировать этот модуль куда нужно. Например файл links.py, в котором хранить ссылки как константы. Потом его импортировать как import  links. И юзать в виде links.LINK1.

Answer (score 4):

Можно просто выносить константы и конфигурации в отдельные модули:

main.py

```
import constants as const
print(const.GOOGLE_SEARCH_LINK)
print(const.DOCUMENTATION)
```

constants.py

```
GOOGLE_SEARCH_LINK = 'https://google/com/search?q='
DOCUMENTATION = """
Simple docs
"""
```